# Mean value properties of $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, multivariable-calculus

I am stuck on the following question which I came across in a recent exam paper:

> Let $f \colon [\pi,2 \pi] \to \Bbb R^2$ be the function $f(t)=(\cos t,\sin t)$.Then which of the following are necessarily correct? The options are:
>
> 1. There exists $t_0 \in [\pi,2\pi]$ such that $f'(t_0)=\frac{f(2 \pi)-f(\pi)}{\pi}$
> 2. There exists no $t_0 \in [\pi,2\pi]$ such  that $f'(t_0)=\frac{f(2 \pi)-f(\pi)}{\pi}$
> 3. There exists $t_0 \in [\pi,2\pi]$ such that $||f(2 \pi)-f(\pi)|| \le \pi ||f'(t_0)||$
> 4. $f'(t)=(-\sin t,\cos t) \,\,\forall t \in [\pi,2\pi]$.

### MY ATTEMPT:

Clearly option 4 is correct but I am not sure how to prove/disprove for other options. Looking at options 1,2,3 I think mean value theorem has a role to play.  Can someone explain me with some details.

My edit:  Option 3 appears to be true since $||f(2 \pi)-f(\pi)||=||(1,0)-(-1,0)||=||(2,0)||=2$ and $\pi ||f'(t_0)||=\pi \,\,\text{since}\, ||f'(t)||=||(- \sin t,\cos t)||=1$ and so $||f(2 \pi)-f(\pi)|| \le \pi ||f'(t_0)||$ is true.

Option 1 makes no sense after putting the values of $\pi, 2\pi$ in $f$. So option 2 appears to be correct. Am I going in the right direction? Is there any other elegant way of tackling this problem?

Comment: Have you already tried to solve directly the equation for $t_0$ in 1./2.?

Comment: What have you tried? If you know 4 is true, why not you substitute it into 1,2,3? Make your life easier by writing out what $f(2\pi)$ and $f(\pi)$ are explicitly.

Comment: In fact, 1 is wrong, while 2 is correct.

Comment: What elegant way are you expecting? The point of the question is to show you while the mean value theorem fails for higher dimensions (see point 2), the mean value *inequality* is still true (see point 3). You can try and prove this in general.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**

1) This is the parametrization of the lower half of the circle $x^2+y^2=1$. So, your function is

$$ y = -\sqrt{1-x^2}, \, x\in[-1,1]. $$

2) Check [Rolle's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rolle%27s_theorem).

**Added:** For $(1)$, you can just do straightforward calculations

$$ \frac{f(2\pi)-f(\pi)}{\pi}=\frac{1}{\pi}(2,0)=\left( \frac{2}{\pi},0 \right)\longrightarrow(1), $$

and

$$ f'(t)=(-\sin(t), \cos(t)) \longrightarrow (2). $$

Now, equate $(1)$ and $(2)$ and try to find $t$ if it exists.

Comment: What are you talking about??

Comment: Isn't clear what's he talking about, @user71815? What's unclear to you?

Comment: @DonAntonio What do you get out of Rolle's theorem in this case? Don't you still need to work out $f'(t)$ in order to check 1 to 4?